# How can I pass info from a Form component to another component to render dynamic data stored in an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm doing a little test that mimic a dog encyclopedia. There is a Data.js that store all the info (dog name, origin... Another component Form.jsx renders a dropdown menu where you can select your dog. This component expands the options using the .map method. There is one last component called DogCard, this one should render all the info stored in Data.js once you select a dog in the Form component. I think I have to pass props but I don't know exactly how to do it.

This is the Form component:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { dogs } from '../components/Data';
import '../stylesheets/Form.css';

function Form ({onDogChange}) {

  const [selectedDog, setSelectedDog] = useState('Pug')

  const handleChange = e => {
    setSelectedDog(e.target.value)
    onDogChange(selectedDog)
  }

  return (
    <>
      <label className="choose" htmlFor='dogs'>Choose your dog:
      <select value={selectedDog} onChange={handleChange}>
        {dogs.map((dog) => (
          <option
            className="option" 
            key={dog.name} 
          >
            {dog.name}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
      </label>
      <p>Your favorite dog: {selectedDog}</p>
    </>
  )
}

export default Form;
```

This is the DogCard component with hardcode:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import { dogs } from '../components/Data';

function DogCard() {


  return (
    <>
      <Form />
      <div className="container">
        <img 
          className="fotodog"
          src={`../../public/imagenes/${dogs[0].image}.jpg`}
          alt='texto'
          />
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="dogname">{dogs[0].name}</p>
          <p className="origin">{dogs[0].origin}</p>
          <p className="phrase">{dogs[0].phrase}</p>
          <p className="trivia">{dogs[0].trivia}</p>  
        </div> 
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default DogCard
```

and finally here is an example of how the data is stored:

```
export const dogs = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Pug',
  image: 'pug',
  alttext: 'Image of a pug',
  origin: 'China',
  phrase: '50% doggy 50% piggy',
  trivia: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.'
},
{
  id: 2,
  name: 'Greyhound',
  image: 'greyhound',
  alttext: 'Image of a greyhond ',
  origin: 'España',
  phrase: 'Run run run!',
  trivia: 'Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident'
},
{
  id: 3,
  name: 'Husky',
  image: 'husky',
  alttext: 'image of a husky',
  origin: 'Rusia',
  phrase: 'So hot here!',
  trivia: 'Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt'
}
```

there is also an App component than renders every component

I've been working on this a few days and I watched many videos and read info about passing props but I don' know how to make this thing work, I tried to pass a prop "onDogChange" but I don't know exactly how to pass it. Tried also .find method but it doesn't work. Can anyone help me please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

In React, we call it hoisting. You can hoist the state to the parent component (In this case the `DogCard`), here's the sample code:

DogCard:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import { dogs } from '../components/Data';

function DogCard() {
  const [dogId, setDogId] = useState(0);

  return (
    <>
      <Form dogId={dogId} onDogIdChange={setDogId} />
      <div className="container">
        <img
          className="fotodog"
          src={`../../public/imagenes/${dogs[dogId].image}.jpg`}
          alt="texto"
        />
        <div className="text-container">
          <p className="dogname">{dogs[dogId].name}</p>
          <p className="origin">{dogs[dogId].origin}</p>
          <p className="phrase">{dogs[dogId].phrase}</p>
          <p className="trivia">{dogs[dogId].trivia}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default DogCard;
```

Form:

```
import React from 'react';
import { dogs } from '../components/Data';
import '../stylesheets/Form.css';

function Form({ dogId, onDogIdChange }) {
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    onDogIdChange(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <label className="choose" htmlFor="dogs">
        Choose your dog:
        <select value={dogId} onChange={handleChange}>
          {dogs.map((dog) => (
            <option className="option" key={dog.id} value={dog.id}>
              {dog.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
      </label>
      <p>Your favorite dog: {dogs[dogId].name}</p>
    </>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Comment: It worked! thank you very much! I'm having some troubles trying to understand how React works and your explanation was very helpful. :)

Comment: @PedroArévalo When someone answers your question and you're happy with the solution, you should mark the question as "answered" by clicking the grey checkmark in the top left corner of the answer. It rewards the answerer with points (ie: reputation) and makes it easier to see the correct answer for future readers.